Removing duplicate rows from a CSV in Excel when one column matches, place results in a new sheet and duplicates in another
I have a long CSV I need to remove duplicates from, but need to keep duplicates and data about where they've come from. My basic Excel macro does half the work but need a hand getting all the way there:
I need to:

Search a range in sheet "OldList" for duplicates based on the email column, ignoring the other columns (in example, Row 3 "Bob" is called "Bobins" in row 5, headers are in row 1).
Create a new sheet called "NewList" in the same workbook with all Duplicates removed, deleting later repeats (So deleting Row 5 here).
Create additional new sheet "Removed Duplicates" in the same workbook with removed Duplicates and reference for where it was removed from.

Example input data:



Name
Email
Other Data




Adam
adam@email.com
123


Bob
bob@email.com
234


Charles
charles@email.com
2345


Bobins
bob@email.com
5334



Desired output sheet:



Name
Email
Other Data




Adam
adam@email.com
123


Bob
bob@email.com
234


Charles
charles@email.com
2345



Desired removed duplicates sheet:



Name
Email
Other Data
Old location




Bobins
bob@email.com
5334
Row 6



Current code:
Sub test()
ActiveSheet.Range("A:C").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=2, Header:=xlYes
End Sub


Thanks @jonrsharpe for the corrections. The editor wouldn't accept my tables in Markdown without wrapping them in code tags for some reason, so I was forced to lay them out like that.
I did attempt to follow the posting guidelines, apologies for falling short there.

A CSV file holds one sheet only so where will you be creating the new sheets or do they already exist? Will they be in the workbook containing this code or in a 3rd workbook? What are the names of the sheets? You're mentioning rows 4 and 6 while it is obvious that they are rows 3 and 5. Are your headers in row 2? If so, do you also want to copy row 1? Your code reveals that your data is in 9 columns. Will column Old Location be column 10 or do you only want to copy the first 3 columns? Please clarify be editing your post (not in the comments) and add some relevant code.

Thank you @VBasic2008 , adjusted. Annoyingly, when I edit the post it won't let me save without turning the tables into code block. Just tells me they are code when I try to save and won't let me proceed.

A reference to the duplicate's source such as "Row 6" won't be of much use once all the duplicates have been removed though?

The reference will still work when comparing with the OldList sheet though

Split Worksheet by Duplicates
Sub SplitByDupes()

    ' Reference the workbook.
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = Workbooks("OldList.csv")
    
    ' Return the values of the table in an array.
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Sheets(1)
    Dim sData() As Variant: sData = sws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value
    ' For fewer columns, 
    ' use e.g. 'sws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Columns("A:C").Value'
    
    ' Define the backup array.
    Dim sRowsCount As Long: sRowsCount = UBound(sData, 1)
    Dim sColumnsCount As Long: sColumnsCount = UBound(sData, 2)
    Dim bColumnsCount As Long: bColumnsCount = sColumnsCount + 1
    Dim bData() As Variant: ReDim bData(1 To sRowsCount, 1 To bColumnsCount)
    
    ' Define a dictionary whose keys will hold each distinct email.
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    
    ' Write the backup array headers.
    Dim c As Long
    For c = 1 To sColumnsCount
        bData(1, c) = sData(1, c)
    Next c
    bData(1, c) = "Old Location"
    
    ' Write the destination and backup data.
    ' If an email doesn't exist in the dictionary, it will be added to it
    ' and the row will be copied to the top of the source (destination) array.
    ' If an email exists, the row will be copied to the top of the backup array.
    Dim dRowsCount As Long: dRowsCount = 1
    Dim bRowsCount As Long: bRowsCount = 1
    Dim sRow As Long, sString As String
    For sRow = 2 To sRowsCount
        sString = CStr(sData(sRow, 2))
        If Len(sString) > 0 Then
            If dict.Exists(sString) Then
                bRowsCount = bRowsCount + 1
                For c = 1 To sColumnsCount
                    bData(bRowsCount, c) = sData(sRow, c)
                Next c
                bData(bRowsCount, c) = "Row" & sRow
            Else
                dict.Add sString, Empty
                dRowsCount = dRowsCount + 1
                For c = 1 To sColumnsCount
                    sData(dRowsCount, c) = sData(sRow, c)
                Next c
            End If
        End If
    Next sRow
        
    ' Create destination.
    With wb.Sheets.Add(After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count))
        .Name = "NewList"
        .Range("A1").Resize(dRowsCount, sColumnsCount).Value = sData
    End With
    
    ' Create backup (of duplicates).
    With wb.Sheets.Add(After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count))
        .Name = "Removed Duplicates"
        .Range("A1").Resize(bRowsCount, bColumnsCount).Value = bData
    End With

    ' Inform.
    MsgBox "Data split by duplicates.", vbInformation

End Sub


Thanks for this, will test tomorrow and respond
